# Can geom_label draw points to a position on a map?

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2

I am making a map using `ggplot2`, and I'd like to place some point labels off (in the margin of the map or what could be a margin) the map with some text describing the point. For instance, the following code produces:

```
require(tidyverse)

# UK Base polygon 
UK <- map_data(map = "world", region = "UK",interior = T) 

# Cities to plot as geom_points
UK_cities <- world.cities %>% 
    filter(country.etc == 'UK')

# Filter for the ones of interest
UK_cities <- UK_cities %>% 
    filter(name %in% c('London',
                   'Edinburgh',
                   'Glasgow',
                   'Birmingham',
                   'Edinburgh'))

# plot with ggplot    
ggplot(data = UK, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
    geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),fill = 'grey80',
                 color = 'grey80') + 
    geom_point(data = UK_cities,aes(long, lat,group = name))+
    geom_text(data = UK_cities,
              aes(long, lat,label = name,group = name),
              color = 'black',
              size  = 3)+
    coord_map()+
    theme_void()
```

Which produces:
[image]

My question is: Can `geom_label` 'draw' a line to a given point and be positioned elsewhere on the map/plot? I'd like to have 'London' off to the side with a small blurb of information, i.e. population, etc. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you checked out the `ggrepel` package?

Comment: Yes,  but I can't seem to position the labels where I'd like them to go exactly.

Comment: Though I suppose I could do them one at a time?

Comment: Since you say you can't position them exactly--that's the trade-off with using `ggrepel`. It applies a jitter that you don't have full control over. But check out the arguments to `geom_text_repel`, because there are some ways to manage the positioning by adjusting `force`, `direction`, `hjust`, etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `ggrepel`'s `geom_text_repel` method:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(maps)
library(ggrepel)

# UK Base polygon 
UK <- map_data(map = "world", region = "UK",interior = T) 

# Cities to plot as geom_points
UK_cities <- world.cities %>% 
  filter(country.etc == 'UK')

# Filter for the ones of interest
UK_cities <- UK_cities %>% 
  filter(name %in% c('London',
                     'Edinburgh',
                     'Glasgow',
                     'Birmingham',
                     'Edinburgh'))

# plot with ggplot    
plot = ggplot(data = UK, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),fill = 'grey80',
               color = 'grey80') + 
  geom_point(data = UK_cities,aes(long, lat,group = name))+
  geom_text_repel(data = UK_cities,
            aes(long, lat,label = name,group = name),
            color = 'black',
            size  = 3,
            box.padding = 0.7, point.padding = 0.5) +
  coord_map()+
  theme_void()


print(plot)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you repell labels to be outside polygons?